# Elasticsearch Dedupe result, return 1 doc for each "field value"

Tags: elasticsearch

For say, we have our indices like this:

```
{"id":1, "country":"cn", "keywords":"kwd1 kwd2"}
{"id":2, "country":"cn", "keywords":"kwd1 kwd3"}
{"id":3, "country":"us", "keywords":"kwd1 kwd5"}
{"id":4, "country":"us", "keywords":"kwd1 kwd4"}
```

Then we query the by the 
    {"term":{"keywords": "kwd1"}.

Normally we will get the result with all 4 docs returned.

However, what if I only need 1 doc for each "country" value returned? In another word, how can I get the result "deduped by field("country")'s value?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**one way**: you could look on facets or aggregations

**another way**: have parent index with countries and child index for keywords, and use top_children query

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I've spent some time on "facets", however, so far I only get the "facets" can get the "count of distinct country value", like we know in the result there are "2 cn, 2 us", but how can I use this facets result to only get "1" for each "distinct country value"? thx.

Comment: then in 2 steps:

you could use stats facet against `id` field value, and group by `country`. So you will have something in result:

{cn: { min: 1, max: 2, average: ...}, us: { min: 3, max: 4, ...}}

and second step is get documents by `id`, and use `min` value as filter by `id`. However, you can't implement pagination, because facet results will be limited, thought you have limited set of countries, so this is ok.